# Request work with POST but with PUT I got 400 error

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, postman, http-method

I'm trying to send a PUT request to my server from Postman, but i keep getting a status 400 Bad Request error, but with POST it works as expected.

When I change the annotation @PutMapping to @PostMapping, it works without changing anything else.

My Controller code :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/articles")
public class ArticleController {
private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(ArticleController.class);

private ArticleService articleService;

@Value("${articles.default.page_size}")
private int articlesDefaultPageSize;

@Autowired
public void setArticleService(ArticleService articleService) {
    this.articleService = articleService;
}

@PutMapping("/update")
public ResponseEntity<Article> update(@ModelAttribute @Validated ArticleDTO articleDTO,
        @AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUserDetails currentUser) {
    LOG.trace(currentUser.getUsername() + " wants to update an article : " + articleDTO);
    Article a = articleService.updateExpertArticle(articleDTO, (Expert) currentUser.getUser());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(a);
}

}
```

The request I send from Postman : [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3mhK.png]

ArticleDTO class :

```
package org.mql.dto;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArticleDTO {
private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(ArticleDTO.class);

private String id;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String title;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String content;

    private MultipartFile[] images;

    private LocalDateTime creationDate;

    public ArticleDTO() {
        LOG.trace("--------Instantiate ArticleDTO -------");
    }

    public MultipartFile[] getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(MultipartFile... images) {
        LOG.trace("--------Set Images-------");
        this.images = images;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
        LOG.trace("--------Set Titles-------");
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
        LOG.trace("--------Set Content-------");
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        LOG.trace("--------Set Id-------");
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(LocalDateTime creationDate) {
        LOG.trace("--------Set Date-------");
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ArticleDTO{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", content='" + content + '\'' +
                ", images=" + Arrays.toString(images) +
                ", creationDate=" + creationDate +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I'm getting in my console :

[image]

Comment: Please include the `ArticleDTO`. What is the reponse body? Does the validation fail? Do you have a stack trace in the logs?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not a question of validation or anything, cause when I change the annotation PutMapping to PostMapping, it works.

Comment: Is the method actually called?

Comment: Sorry @Turing85, I edited the post, and added more information

Comment: I would recommend setting a breakpoint on the method defining the `@PutMapping` and stepping through the execution.

Comment: I tried to do so, I found that when I'm using `@ PostMapping`, the `articleDTO` constains my params sent with Postman, but when I'm using `@ PutMapping`,all `articleDTO` fields are `null`

Comment: Try adding @RequestBody to ArticleDTO.

Comment: Thanks @Suman, It works.

Comment: Added as answer. Do accept to help others.

Comment: @CïKõ I would, if I had downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding @RequestBody to ArticleDTO.